Will movers be able to get washer/dryer unit out of closet?
Replacing my washer dryer unit, and noticed that my washer and dryer is actually taller than the entrance of the closet door... there's still about a few inches of ceiling inside the closet but not sure how they even got the washer/dryer unit into the closet in the first place (in a condo unit, bought the place years ago)
Anyone know if they'll be able to move this out to put in my new ones (the new ones fit, the height of the door is 80" and my new one's height is 76")


They went in somehow...

How did they get in there? If they really can't fit through the opening, that means the previous owner specifically built a too-small opening around them after they were installed, which I suppose is possible, but  wouldn't make much sense.

They look like two pieces.  So take the washer out first, then the dryer can drop(be moved down carefully) and out.  Not saying it will fun for the movers, and should let them know before the moving day.

omg i feel like an idiot... you're right @crip659 the washer just slides out... i've been trying to move the whole frame thinking they were 1 unit... ok ya i'll have to let the movers know about this, thanks!

Unless they are broken/rusted out, you can probably get decent money for them from old foggies like me who think modern stuff is garbage.  If mine were needing replacement, I would look for that type of machine.

unfortunately they're probably just going to be hauled away by whoever Costco sends to deliver my new ones... dont have any space to keep them in the condo :(

call Boys and Girls club ... I think that they accept donations of furniture and appliances ... or call Salvation Army ... they might accept the appliances for people in need

Local churches/Goodwill are another couple.  Most of them will remove for free also.  There is a joke on facebook with an 80s fridge that it will outlast everyone.  Not much of a joke since most of them are still working.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not about home improvement.

At our vacation condo, they need to take the door & jambs off to get the unit in and out.  But the local appliance people have done this for years and do a good, careful job of removing the jambs and replacing them.

Heck, just throw them up for free on Facebook Marketplace or Craigslist free stuff.  You may have to store them in the condo temporarily while you deal with all the tire kickers, but it's better than putting them in a landfill like Costco will do.

Are you suuuuuuuure you know what the provided hookups are behind there?  If the washer-dryer came with the condo, it is VERY common to find they used "trick" washer-dryers which eliminate the hot water connection, daisy chain washer power off dryer to avoid having a 120V circuit, and/or eliminate the dryer vent.  People buy random cheap appliances and surprise! The infra is not there to support them.

lift the drier up pull it forwards and tilt it backwards.
The shelf that supports the drier is a separate part
and the washer is also separate.
